# Getting notified about a change of a public variable in a script

Tags: unity, c#

I have a script attached to a GameObject.

In this script I have the variable `public int Rotation`

If this value is changed, I need to do some calculations.

I know that I can be notified when this value is changed in the Inspector (for example if somebody enters a different number), but I would like to be notified if this value is changed by another script.

Is that possible, or do I need do introduce a `void ChangeRotation(int uNewValue)` or similiar?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a property:

```
[SerializeField]
private int _rotation;
public int rotation {
    get { return _rotation; }

    set {
        // Act on the change here.
        _rotation = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also combine property and event:

```
private float _rotation;
public event Action <float> OnRotationChange;
public float Rotation {
    get { return _rotation; }
    set {
        _rotation = value;
        OnRotationChange?.Invoke (value);
    }
}
```

Subscribe to event:

```
scriptInstance.OnRotationChange += Handler;
```

where `Handler` is a method with one `float` parameter. When rotation changes, the event fires, and all its handlers get called.

When you no longer need the object that reacts to the event, **unsubscribe** from it:

```
scriptInstance.OnRotationChange -= Handler;
```

#### Be careful!

If you don't unsubscribe, it's a performance and memory leak, because the event remembers the handler and calls it, and prevents GC from collecting the object that is no longer in use.